# Firebase storage rules are not letting images to upload

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am not sure what happened but I receive an error uploading images to the website. I do have a weird structure, though:

> this.storage.ref('storyImages/'+ this.user.id +'/'+ storyId
>   +'/'+ this.generateUID() + imageFile.name).put(imageFile);

Right now I am getting error uploading images:

> xhrio_network.js:62 POST
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projectname.appspot.com/o?name=storyImages%2FOaRLRdN6UUaptZA4T8kMl2bTxBt1%2FD2qPuty7Yjl49a1LyFQ3%2Fm3yblp232866fcceb5952bddaf6d696cbee936.jpg&upload_id=AEnB2UoROqdWIw2lO4wAT4WxCPaH6yy4Hne8sE-bf_AeDU93J45sDADXyat-cT3xPsBMXKUJAtevJ0Doa0NNIGxlIHoxvM2LwA&upload_protocol=resumable
>   403 ()

Which is access denied error. Everything worked before so the only thing I may think of are rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /storyImages {
     // Cascade read to any image type at any path
     match /{allImages=**} {
       allow read;
     }

     // Allow write files, subject to the constraints:
     // 1) File is less than 1MB
     // 2) Content type is an image
     // 3) Uploaded content type matches existing content type
     // 4) File name (stored in imageId wildcard variable) is less than 120 characters
     // 5) UserId should be the same as folder name where user writes
     match /{userId}/{storyId}/{imageId} {
       allow write: if request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
                    && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
                    && request.resource.contentType == resource.contentType
                    && imageId.size() < 120
                    && request.auth != null
                    && request.auth.uid == userId
     }
   }
 }
}
```

But I can't find any errors here. Any help? If there is not enough information here just ask I will add more. Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
request.resource.contentType == resource.contentType
```

brings the error. If anyone knows how to fix this and continue to check the file type I still need some ways to implement that. Moreover, this line was from [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files) so I assumed it must work and skipped that in the first check.

Comment: It will fail for new uploads since no resource is existing. You should append the security rules that allows upload if the resource is null like 

     match /{userId}/{storyId}/{imageId} {
       allow write: if resource == null || (request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
                    && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
                    && request.resource.contentType == resource.contentType
                    && imageId.size() < 120
                    && request.auth != null
                    && request.auth.uid == userId)